# css: vertical align issue with inline-block divs

Tags: html, css

I need to center a message in a div, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sDWxN/1/)
The parent div has a width of 100%, and to center the message horizontally is no problem. Also, as you can see, the icon is also centered vertically, but I cannot center the text vertically. So far, the only css I've applied to that div is

```
.content {
    height: 100% ;
    display: inline-block ;
}
```

Any suggestions why the message div is shifted downwards in the .container. And is this the right cross browser approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with minimum changes to your **DOM** and **CSS**, and without fixing any *height / line-height*

add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.icon` and replace `height:100%` with `vertical-align: middle;` in `.content`

see this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/sDWxN/7/)

Answer (score 2):

change your css like this

```
.content {
height: 100% ;
display: inline-block ;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:5px;
}

.container {
display: inline-block ;
height: 100% ;
}
```

[Check The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/sDWxN/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
.parent {
    background-color: lightgrey ;
    width: 100% ;
    height: 50px ;
    text-align: center ;  
    display: inline-block;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -15px; //so that text lies at the center level of icon
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/sDWxN/2/

The `.container` height is a problem and you can put the `.container` height at 100% to make it adjusted to its parent. After add `vertical-align:middle;` to the `.content`.

```
.content {
    height: 100% ;
    display: inline-block ;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block ;
    height: 100% ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should somehow do the trick. 
http://jsfiddle.net/sDWxN/6/

basically, I added this:

The markup

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">    
    <div class="content">
        <div class="icon">
            <p class="tocenter">some message here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block ;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Red_triangle_alert_icon.png) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat ;
    background-position: 0 ;
    background-size: 8% ;
    width: 250px ;
    height: 100% ;
}
.content {    
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 100% ;    
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

[Another approach](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kKeDq).

I prefer to have the message and the icon 'related' in a span with a child span. Two keys in this approach:

1. Vertically align the **container** div inside the **parent** one. Using **position** in both classes, and **margin** in **container**, you can achieve that.
2. Vertically align the **span** with the message inside the parent **span** (the one with the icon, which use the **icon-message** class). See the comments in the css code.

It works in every browser.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="icon-message">
            <span>message</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    background-color: lightgrey ;
    width: 100% ;
    height: 70px ;
    text-align: center ; 
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px ;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.icon-message {
    background: url( "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Red_triangle_alert_icon.png" ) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 40px 40px; /* image's size */
    height: 40px; /* image's height */
    padding-left: 50px; /* image's width plus 10 px (margin between text and image) */
}

.icon-message span {
    height: 40px; /* image's height */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```